# Synchronizing Visual SVN with IIS for web development (or to any other folder)

Tags: windows, svn, iis, iis-7, visualsvn-server

How to get the latest version of the project file to another folder on every commit?

I'm using VisualSVN server and I think we can do this on post-commit in hooks, but I don't know how. Server is on Windows.

Actually I need to get the latest version of the file to `\www` folder of IIS7. Simply, get the latest file to another folder.

Comment: so is your script above not doing anything? Is it your svn.exe that handles the copying of the latest version to your www folder?

Comment: that code doing nothing, if I run this on command prompt it is working. but on committing, it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added following code in post-commit hook (for copying latest version files to `D:\Destination`).

```
svn export --force file:///D:/Repositories/myproject D:\Destination
exit 2
```

It works fine for me.

If your trying to export this to a directory of website, need to change the directory permission. Visual SVN is using NETWORK SERVICE.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same file in more than single folder inside your repository and you Subversion is 1.6 or newer, you can use file-type of svn:externals without binding to revision.

In this case committed to SOURCE file will be updated in Working Copy of TARGET after usual `svn up`

Comment: Thanks.
I'm new to svn and i need to update the file in www folder on each committ. how can it do this? also this is in windows. :)

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how

You correctly say that you have to do it by post-commit, but if you mean you don't know the process, here is how.

Your post-commit hook is a script which is called after every commit to a project in your SVN repository. There is a file called `post-commit` in the hooks folder of every repository. Change the file to include the necessary commands* to do the copying for you and make it an executable `post-commit.exe`.

Afterwards, every time you commit a new revision, that script should handle it for you.

*By necessary commands I mean, either do the copying via the Windows cmd prompt, or call another script to do the job from within `post-commit.exe`.

Also, even though SVN docs mention that the post-commit hook needs to be either `.bat` or `.exe` file, I've had it working only when it's `.exe` on my machine.

You can convert `.bat` files into binary `.exe` using tools available [here](http://bat2exe.net/) and [here](http://bat2exe.codeplex.com/). The second one is much more user-friendly. I hope it helps.

Comment: ys @mavili, this what I'm also doing... may be commands are wrong. can you please help me to check it?

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha but you say in your comment that running this script on its own it runs, but not with commit, right?

Comment: Ys @mavili. Its not running with commit.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/482257/visualsvn-server-doesnt-trigger-post-commit-hook

Comment: Thank you. I'm checking that. I'm a beginner in SVN, finally I changed the code in post-commit by this `svn update D:\Destination –quiet –non-interactive –username mansoor –password mypass` 
Now when I'm committing a file, RapidSVN is going to stuck. I think something is happening. But nothing is happend, :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34063/discussion-between-mansoorkhan-cherupuzha-and-mavili)